# iOS logic for presenting login button or actual content in a VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Right now I have 2 `UIView` container at the same hierarchy, **one containing a login button** (that modally presents a login vc) and **the other containing the actual content**. Logic to show these views corresponds to the following code:

```
loginView.hidden = isLogged
actualView.hidden = !isLogged
```

These work, but it makes it really hard to work on interface builder, as each time I'm modifying the underlying view, I have to move the front one and constraint get all messed up.

Is there any way to get the same behaviour but instead of overlapping 2 views with `.hidden = true/false`, it is managed by a controller or similar? (i.e: `if logged present actual VC, else present VC with a login button`)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get the same behaviour but instead of overlapping 2 views with `.hidden = true/false`, it is managed by a controller or similar? (i.e: `if logged present actual VC, else present VC with a login button`)

Yes. You can move your login view into a [nib](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) that you [load in code](https://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/quick-reference-load-a-uiview-created-in-a-nib/). You will still have to either show and hide, or load and unload the nib as needed; however, doing it this way will remove the clutter from your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to do stuff like this I put this presentation login in `AppDelegate`. I code a function that decides which VC must be presented, according to login state.

```
    func showInitialViewControllerForUserState(isLogged: Bool) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var targetViewController: UIViewController? = nil

    if isLogged {
        targetViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoggedViewControllerController") as! UINavigationController
    } else  {
        targetViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController

    }

    targetViewController!.view.alpha = 0

    self.window?.rootViewController = targetViewController
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) { () -> Void in
        targetViewController!.view.alpha = 1
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!